# Find the probability that at least one of poker opponents hits a card

Tags: percentages, poker

In Texas hold'em, when you see the flop there is about 33% chance that one of your 2 cards hits something on the flop, maybe not exactly but let's say it's 33% that your opponent did hit something on the flop with his 2 pocket cards. Let's say you have 2 opponents with you in the pot, then it should be 66% that one of them hit something, 3 opponents 99%? Well maybe but when there are 4 more people after you then it can't be 132% that doesn't make sense, there is no 100%, how do I calculate that correctly?

Comment: The problem with that that you need to multiply the probability: $1/3$ probability for you, and if your opponent finds something too, then its $1/3*1/3=1/9$, not $1/3+1/3=2/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximation to the probability of at least one of them hitting would be 100% minus the probability of them both NOT hitting.  Or
$$1-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{5}{9}$$
The probability of at least one of THREE players hitting would be
$$1-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{19}{27}$$

This doesn't work exactly this way because of the way each players hand affects each other, (shared cards, etc.) but is an approximation.

Comment: Thank you, we don't have to worry about shared cards, we only exclude cards that we know are out of the deck for sure, like the ones on board and the ones I am holding, thats how you do things in poker.

Comment: That is not right.  Those are not independent event.  You hold a blocker.

Comment: @Paparazzi Correct. I tried to make clear in my answer that this was an approximation.